# Will Windows XP work on a Hybrid Hard Drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot

I'm looking into getting the [Seagate Momentus XT](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148591) hybrid hard drive, and I'm planning on dual booting between Windows 7 and Windows XP. I know 7 and Vista have native support for taking advantage of the SSD portion of a hybrid drive, and I assume XP does not have any such support, but will XP still *work* on the drive? I would think it will, but I wanted to be sure, and the Googles are coming up empty for me on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know someone that has that drive and does have XP running on it.

Comment: Great. I did a bit more digging, and it looks like you're right. Obviously, I just have to make sure I slipstream in the SATA drivers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will work I also have one, the TRIM function wont work in XP however.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Although the Momentus XT is a "hybrid hard drive", its onboard NVRAM cache is completely invisible to the OS, so the OS need not implement what MS called "ReadyDrive" and would never send it TRIM commands, or any other NVRAM-specific commands,  anyway. Management of the Momentus XT's cache is strictly done by the firmware on the drive. It was specifically designed that way so as to work with any OS. See http://techreport.com/review/18989/seagate-momentus-xt-hard-drive